# Improper Integral Polynomial to negative exponent

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I'm trying to do the following question:
Spivak Chapter 14 Problem 25

**The limit $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{a}^{\infty}f$, if it exists, is denoted by $\int_{a}^{\infty}f$, and called an "improper integral".**

a) Determine $\int_{1}^{\infty}x^r$, if $r<-1$

c) Suppose that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$ and that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ exists. Prove that if $0\leq g(x)\leq f(x)$ for all $x\geq 0$, and g is integrable on each interval $[0,N]$, then $\int_{0}^{\infty}g$ also exists.

**What I tried:** For item a) I didn't have many ideas, the only that occurred to me was trying to partition the interval $[0, N]$ in equal intervals and try to fiddle with upper and lower sums, but as the exponent is negative I couldn't do much, and don't think that's the way.
For item c) I believe that doing a) wouldn't help directly, so my idea was simply to use the fact that, as g is integrable on each interval $[0, N]$ the limit in the improper integral makes sense and thus $\int_{0}^{\infty}g$ would also exist, but that's most definitely wrong as I didn't rely on the other hypotheses, though I can't think of something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1]** For your first question. You can first calculate
$$
\int_{1}^{N}x^{r}\text{d}x=\left[\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}\right]^{N}_{1}=\frac{N^{r}}{r+1}-\frac{1}{r+1}
$$
And $r<-1$ hence 
$$
\frac{N^{r}}{r+1} \underset{N \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}0
$$
So

> $$
> \int_{1}^{+\infty}x^{r}\text{d}x=-\frac{1}{r+1}
> $$

In particular you have
$$
\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{x^2}=1$$

**2]** The second is a little harder, consider the function $G$ given by
$$
G\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{x}g\left(t\right)\text{d}t
$$
You know that $g \geq 0$ hence $G$ which is its antiderivative, is increasing. Furthermore for all $x$
$$
G\left(x\right) \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}f\left(t\right)\text{d}t
$$
It is increasing and is majorated, hence $G$ admits a limit. So $g$ is integrable. You can " adjust " it with sequences instead of functions which will fit more to the question.

Comment: Thank you. As a follow-up question, it's the last item of this question which i forgot to put in the description, it possible to prove that integrals such as $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2+1}$ exist using the second part of the problem? I was trying to find a function whose integral was easy to find and that is always greater than it and that converges as it would solve it, but the most immediate ideas, $\frac{1}{x^2}, \frac{1}{x^2-1}, \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$ don't work

Comment: Can't you use that $$\text{tan}^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ hence $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ ?